# Range Request in ASP.NET MVC - Failed to play with Google browser and Opera

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lib.web.mvc

I'm using this library [here](https://github.com/tpeczek/Lib.Web.Mvc) and I'm using this plugin [here](http://videojs.com/) to play the video.

Follow the code:

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult StreamUploadedVideo()
{            
    byte[] test = null;

    using (var ctx = new Entities())
    {
        var result = ctx.Table.Where(x => x.Field == 4).FirstOrDefault();

        test = result.Movie;

        return new RangeFileContentResult(test, "video/mp4", "Name.mp4", DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="@Url.Action("StreamUploadedVideo","Controller")" type='video/mp4'>
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
        <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
</video>
```

**Problem:** When I change the video time (example: change the time from 1:00 to 10:00 minutes), I face this problem below:

Google Chrome: `A network error caused the media download to fail part-way.`

Opera: `The media playback was aborted due to corruption problem or because the used features your browser did not support.`

Image:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

The rest of the browsers are fine. Google and Opera is with the latest updated version of today's date: 07/04/2017

- Micrososft Edge - Ok
- Firefox - Ok
- Internet Explorer - Ok
- Opera - Error
- Google - Error

Any Solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with your code as you are using `DateTime.Now` for `modificationDate` which is used for generating `ETag` and `Last-Modified` headers. As chromium (engine behind Chrome and opera) range requests can be conditional (which means they can contain `If-Match`/`If-None-Match`/`If-Modified-Since`/`If-Unmodified-Since`) it results in `412 Precondition Failed` instead of `200 OK` or `206 Partial Content`. If the underlying content doesn't change you should be using same date, something like this.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult StreamUploadedVideo()
{
    byte[] test = null;
    DateTime lastModificationDate = DateTime.MinValue;

    using (var ctx = new Entities())
    {
        var result = ctx.Table.Where(x => x.Field == 4).FirstOrDefault();

        test = result.Movie;
        lastModificationDate = result.LastModificationDate;
    }

    return new RangeFileContentResult(test, "video/mp4", "Name.mp4", lastModificationDate);
}
```

Comment: Tank you tpeczek

Comment: Hi tpeczek, Is there RangeFileContentResult for asp.net core?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda I've responded under a blog post where you have asked the same question.

Comment: Alright, I asked another question on your blog, please look.